# Laravel Api receiving two requests at the same time

Tags: php, api, laravel-5

I have an api in laravel 5.4 which is consumed by an android application, the problem is that I am having a competition problem, because many times the application sends 2 times the same request at the same time, generating duplicate data in the base. How to avoid this at the Laravel application level? I can not adjust the application because it is done by another company.

As a workaround I am putting a random sleep of 1-15s before the functions to try to prevent the two requests from executing at the same time.

Thank you!

Comment: Unique keys, transactions, etc. Depends a bit on the sort of data being sent.

Comment: That's odd; any APIs I've developed have been able to handle concurrent requests without issue. What kind of "duplicate data" is being generated?
 Are your database tables set up to properly handle uniqueness (auto-incrementing primary key, unique keys, etc etc)?

Comment: Can you show an example of the method handling the request?

Comment: The problem is that my api gets an array of codes that I need to validate if they are active, have already been sent, invalid, among other statuses. What I think I did not make clear is that the Android application is sending the same request at the same time. They are not requests of different instances, it is the same sending the data. If 10 different different devices send, the api has no problem whatsoever.

I solved limiting the 1 request per minute per user for the same request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, unique keys and database transactions are your best bet for preventing data duplication. The documentation has some good examples on where to start.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions

Are you experiencing any record locking issues as a result? You can specify the number of times a transaction should be attempted by passing a second argument to the `DB::transaction()` method.

You have control over manually committing and rolling back transactions, as well. This in conjunction with defining unique indices should prevent duplication from occurring.

Last of all, you can rate limit the requests received by the api through middleware, for example: `['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'throttle:5,10']`

Hopefully this all helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was looking and I found this tool https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle and now it´s works! I put transaction again in any action on database